# Want to parse same structure

Tags: antlr4

I would like to make ANTLR4 parse this:

```
FSM
name type String
state type State
Relation
name type String
```

And i am using this grammar :

```
grammar Generator;

classToGenerate:
    name=Name NL
    (attributes NL)+
    classToGenerate| EOF;
attributes: attribute=Name WS 'type' WS type=Name;

Name:  ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+ ;

WS: (' ' | '\t')+;
NL:  '\r'? '\n';
```

I would like to read successfully, i don't know why, but each time i run my program, i get this error :

```
line 6:18 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
```

Any fix?

Comment: there seems to be a typo: the letter i after your NL rule

Comment: Yes, the `i` must have been a typo: I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailing `EOF` is messing things up for you. Try creating a separate rule that matches the `EOF` token, preceded by one or more `classToGenerate` (the `parse` rule in my example):

```
grammar Generator;

parse
 : classToGenerate+ EOF
 ;

classToGenerate
 : name=Name NL (attributes NL)+
 ;

attributes
 : attribute=Name WS 'type' WS type=Name
 ;

Name:  ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+ ;
WS: (' ' | '\t')+;
NL:  '\r'? '\n';
```

And do you really need to keep the spaces and line breaks? You could let the lexer discard them, which makes your grammar a whole lot easier to read:

```
grammar Generator;

parse
 : classToGenerate+ EOF
 ;

classToGenerate
 : name=Name attributes+
 ;

attributes
 : attribute=Name 'type' type=Name
 ;

Name   : [a-zA-Z]+;
Spaces : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Comment: Oh thanks, it reads without error now, but now it stops here :
state type State

It doesn't parse the rest.

Which is : Relation
name type String

Comment: No problem. Feel free to create a new question if you have a new problem. These comment boxes are not well suited to explain (or answer) your question.